# WPF Grid not showing content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using a Window with a Grid which loads Objects from a MongoDB. These Object contains Lists. Now I want to Load a List from one of these Objects. This is the Source from the Window:

```
    public void btn_load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow M = new MainWindow();
       
        ArtikelLaden();
        M.RefreshGrid();

        Close();
        
    }        
    public void ArtikelLaden()
    {

        MainWindow M = new MainWindow();
        rowindexArtikel = dg_Artikel.SelectedIndex;
        Artikel B = new Artikel();
        B = artikelList[rowindexArtikel];
        M.loadArtikel(B);
    }
```

The List should get loaded in the MainWindow:

```
public void loadArtikel(Artikel B)
    {
        dg_test.ItemsSource = null;
        dg_test.ItemsSource = B.kaufList;
        dg_test.Items.Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show(dg_test.HasItems.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dg_test.Items.Count.ToString());

        dg_Teile.ItemsSource = null;
        dg_Teile.ItemsSource =B.teilList;
        dg_Teile.Items.Refresh();

        //dg_Teile.Items.Refresh();
        //dg_BauGrp.ItemsSource = B.bauList ;
    }
    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
        //dg_Kaufteile.UpdateLayout();
        //dg_Kaufteile.Items.Refresh();
        //dg_Teile.UpdateLayout();
        MessageBox.Show(dg_Kaufteile.HasItems.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dg_Kaufteile.Items.Count.ToString());
    }
```

When you see some curious things in the source is just because I've tested now thousands of possibilities. But the Grids in the MainWindow always simply stays empty.

The first MsgBox says that the grid has Content. Later in second MsgBox in the Refresh Method it says its empty?!

When I load the Lists in the first Window it works. The Grids have AutoColumn enabled.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with MVVM. All the logic with with regard to MongoDB should be handled and coordinated by the view model. Use bindings in XAML. Also, when using ItemsControls (such as ListBox, ComboBox, etc..), you should just use ItemsSource and refrain from ever touching the Items property. If you setup your bindings properly, you will not need to manually call Refresh either. (And why do you set a variable/property, and then set it again right in the next code line (like "B", "dg_test.ItemsSource", "dg_Teile.ItemsSource")? This is quite silly...)

Comment: In WPF you can't just set items that are bound and expect them to just show up in the GUI, you have to notify the property system that new items have been changed.  Look up INPC or DependencyObject for WPF.

Comment: I know its not the perfect / best / right way and mvvm is planned in the future, but i wanted to create a working prototype to learn all the basics and then start with a correct coded GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `MainWindow` but you probably want to access the already existing one that you see on the screen. Try this:

```
public void btn_load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow M = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();

    ArtikelLaden(M);
    M.RefreshGrid();

    Close();
}

public void ArtikelLaden(MainWindow M)
{
    rowindexArtikel = dg_Artikel.SelectedIndex;
    Artikel B = new Artikel();
    B = artikelList[rowindexArtikel];
    M.loadArtikel(B);
}
```